# C++ function takes ints, but example shows text?

Tags: c++, function, int, bit-manipulation

This is a C++ question on something that is confusing me. (I am refreshing my C++ after a long time). I am reading this example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#void%20imshow%28const%20string&%20winname,%20InputArray%20mat%29). There are two parts that confuse me:

The first part:

In the code line:

```
void namedWindow(const string& winname, int flags=WINDOW_AUTOSIZE )
```

WINDOW_AUTOSIZE is an input, but as far as I can tell, it is not an int. When I code this line up and run, it works fine. My input into this function literally is 'WINDOW_AUTOSIZE'. I am confused as to why this works. How is WINDOW_AUTOSIZE an int?

My second question is regarding the last line, whereby they say:

> By default, flags == CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE | CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO |
>   CV_GUI_EXPANDED

I am confused as to how/what this means exactly... I know that | is a bitwise OR, but not clear what this means exactly...

Thank you.

Comment: what did you think `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` was? Strings are delimited by quote marks.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I wasn't sure since I hadn't defined it. But it exists in a header file it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My input into this function literally is 'WINDOW_AUTOSIZE'

Yep, `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` is in fact an integer; **Simply look at the fact that it's a default argument for an `int` function parameter. It wouldn't compile if it wasn't an `int`**

```
// it might have been defined like this
#define WINDOW_AUTOSIZE 23434 // some number just for example
// or like this
const int WINDOW_AUTOSIZE = 34234;
```

As for the second question bitwise `OR`ing means that all bits in the corresponding integral values are `OR`ed together, so lets say for example

```
CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE   = 0x0010 
CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO  = 0x0100
CV_GUI_EXPANDED      = 0x1100
```

then the corresponding operation would give an integral value with every bit equal to the result of `OR` for each position

```
CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE | CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO | CV_GUI_EXPANDED = 

0x0010 
0x0100
0x1100
------
0x1110
```

---

### On the use of bitflags

Consider the following : **You have a keyboard with 4 keys** :

> Ctrl, Alt, Del, Shift

How many constants would you need to define all states this keyboard can be on ? Well lets enumerate the states

1. All 4 keys pressed : **1 constant**
2. 3 keys pressed : It takes (4 by 3) constants = **4 constants** :

   ```
   (4 by 3) = 4! / ( (4-3)! * 3! ) = 4
   ```
3. 2 keys pressed : (4 by 2) = **6 constants**
4. 1 key pressed  : 4 constants (the names of the keys)
5. No key pressed : 1 constant

So to sum up you'd define :

```
1 + 4 + 6 + 4 + 1 = 16 constants
```

Now what if I told you only need 4 **different** constants, **each one having only one bit ON ?** :

```
#define CtrlK  0x0001
#define AltK   0x0010
#define DelK   0x0100
#define ShiftK 0x1000
```

Then any state for the keyboard can be expressed by a combination of the above : Say you want to express the state **Shift key and Del key are pressed**. Then it would be

```
CtrlK | DelK
```

The more combinations you have, the more this technique pays off.

Ofcourse (maybe you could see a reference on bitflags) user code can probe an integral value to see which bits are switched ON.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I guess the last thing I dont understand is *why* they have set 'flag' by default, to be the bitwise OR of three things that are already defined... not seeing the purpose here.

Comment: @Learnaholic Bitflag machinery in this context is used to prevent combinatorial explosion. So you have eg your initial **states**, expressed as bitflags, and any **status** can be expressed as a **combination** of those (mutually exluded) states. It's like saying "the default configuration for the keyboard will be NUM_LOCK=ON and (`&`) CAPS_LOCK=ON" so `INITIAL_STATE = NUM_LOCK & CAPS_LOCK`. That saves you from defining another state

Comment: I am confused here. In your example for example, the result of ORing will be '0x1110'. Ok, good, but what state that does *actually* correspond to? Are you saying this state will be such that I can autoresize, keep the ratio, and gui-expansion at the same time?

Comment: @Learnaholic Yep. That makes sense. Read the description of the flags.

Comment: @Learnaholic I'll edit this in the answer, because it'll be a bit big. Give me a min

Comment: Thanks for the expansion. That makes sense. The key to the un-confusion is that the *bitwise* OR in this particular case, actually implements a *linguistic* AND. That was what was confusing me.

Comment: Actually, the thing is though, that for this to work, all the #define states have to be orthogonal to each other right? Otherwise we would not be able to implement something like this...

Comment: @Learnaholic So much for the extra mile, maybe you should ask under the selected answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt see your comment about expansion till after I finished with commenting on addy. Your expansion is very nice and I truly appreciate it. Let me undo,

Answer (score 5):

The words written in capital letters are *constants*. They have been defined somewhere in the code or in the headers to be used in another place. A constant can stand for a number, string etc. The constants in this code are obviously of the type `int`

`CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE | CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO | CV_GUI_EXPANDED` is just bitwise OR of the `int` values the constants stand for. These are spacial constants where only one bit of the `int` is set (so called *flags*)

Assume, `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` is 0x1 and `CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO` is 0x2. So bitwise OR-ing would result in 0x3. The called function can then check by AND-operation which flag was set.

Comment: Ah, thank you! So you mean they are defined as "#define CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE 1" for example?

Comment: Yes, usually you would use hex numbers, its easier. (0x8 is 1000 binary for example)

Comment: @addy2012 Not because it's easier, but because you can combine single binary digits as masks.

Comment: @JosephMansfield so the conclusion is yes, because it's easier than decimal (unless one knows all the powers of two)

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what i meant ;)

Comment: @addy2012 Ok - that last thing I dont get is the reasoning behind why they have made the default flag like this. I mean, why do they OR three things that are already defined?...

Comment: @Learnaholic Because they decided that these are the three flags that people are most likely to want set by default.

Comment: because you want the combination of all these options. each bit stands for one option (*flag*). OR-ing sets multiple options.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I guess I am not seeing how that works at all. :-( 'flag' is set to a default value of the result of ORing three defined values. Ok, so what? How does that do anything for anything?

Comment: But arent those states mutually exclusive? I dont get it. What is the default state of flag actually set to?

Comment: @Learnaholic They are not mutually exclusive. That is the point of flags! :D Nikos gave you an example in his answer. If you bitwise OR the flags, you get a combination of them.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Ok... so what you are saying is that the default state, is such that I can autoresize, AND keep the picture ratio, AND do gui expansion, but we are using a bitwise OR to get an 'AND' combination of those states? Is that correct?...

Comment: yes. you must distinguish between the technical usage of bitwise OR and the semantic meaning of combining options/flags

Comment: @Learnaholic Well I never really thought about it like that... but yes. Remember these are bitwise ORs, not logical. You need to think in terms of bits: `0010 OR 0100 = 0110`. If we used AND instead, it wouldn't work: `0010 AND 0100 = 0000`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Ok... yes, that was what was confusing me. They *mean* a semantic AND of the states, but it is implemented via a bitwise OR of the states. I think I get it now... thank you for being patient! :-)

Comment: @Learnaholic that's what i wrote above.

Comment: @addy2012 Yeah... I think I get it now. Thanks for being patient! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I belive the WINDOW_AUTOSIZE is not a string or text. It will be a constant or #defined preprocessor constant. So int datatype can accept it. Please check the definition of the WINDOW_AUTOSIZE in the source code.
Also note that we can pass variables with 'char', 'enum' datatypes to a function which accepts int. The conversion to int will happen internally.